# Default Arguments defining static member

Tags: c++, c++11

I m reading The C++ Programming Language 4e. In the part of Default Argument I dont understand below code. I try to compile but there is an error. Anyway what Bjarne trying to explaing? 
 **A default argument is type checked at the time of the function declaration and evaluated at the
time of the call. For example:**

```
class X 
{
    public:
    static int def_arg;
    void f(int = def_arg);
// ...
};
int X::def_arg = 7;
void g(X& a)
{
    a.f(); // maybe f(7)
    a.def_arg = 9;
    a.f(); // f(9)
}
```

Error is :

```
unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall X::f(int)" (?f@X@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl g(class X &)" (?g@@YAXAAVX@@@Z)
```

MS c++ 2013

Comment: What's the error message? -- [_It compiles in gcc-4.8._](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/293f304a2d33f48f)

Comment: This might technically work, but it looks like you can generate really hard to follow code this way, because the default argument is no longer constant.

Comment: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall X::f(int)" (?f@X@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl g(class X &)" (?g@@YAXAAVX@@@Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just declared `f` but need to define the body of `f`:

```
void f(int = def_arg);
```

For example

```
void X::f(int)
{
   // Do something
}
```

or

```
class X 
{
    // ...
    void f(int = def_arg)
    { 
        // Do something
    }
};
```

[*Live code.*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3231780ef4a51a35)

Comment: thanks sir, just one question which ide you want me to use? currently i m using vs c++ 2013.

Comment: You have many choices, I personally use [NetBeans as IDE](https://netbeans.org/) and [MinGW/GCC](http://www.mingw.org/) as C++ compiler. Also you can use [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) which has a MinGW beside -- For testing code snippets I use [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and [makefile](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/).